# Cwacs-camera photos are mirrored no matter what mirrorFFC is set to

Tags: android, camera, commonsware-cwac

I'm having a strange problem with  CommonsWare's [cwac-camera library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera).
Images taken by the front camera are always mirrored (i.e. mirror of what I see in the preview) despite setting:

`builder.mirrorFFC(true);`

I have confirmed that this setting is applied correctly by logging in the ImageCleanupTask as follows:

```
if (applyMatrix) {
  if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
    if (xact.host.getDeviceProfile().portraitFFCFlipped()
        && (xact.displayOrientation == 90 || xact.displayOrientation == 270)) {
      matrix=flip(new Matrix());
    }
    else if (xact.mirrorFFC()) {
      Log.d("myapp", "matrixFFC is true");
      matrix=mirror(new Matrix());
    }
  }
```

The strangest thing is photos are **always** mirrored, whether I set mirrorFFC(true) or not. I haven't made any other changes to the Cwac library.

A quick and dirty hack solving the problem is to modify ImageCleanupTask as follows:

```
if (matrix != null) {
    Bitmap original=
        BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

    cleaned=
        Bitmap.createBitmap(original, 0, 0, original.getWidth(),
                            original.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    original.recycle();

    //below my added code:
    Matrix myMatrix = new Matrix(); 
    myMatrix.preScale(-1.0f, 1.0f);
    cleaned = Bitmap.createBitmap(cleaned, 0, 0, cleaned.getWidth(), cleaned.getHeight(), myMatrix, false);
  }
```

Now the question is - is it simply my device (Samsung SGS i9000, running ICS) that causes problems or something else?

Comment: Do you see the same effect in an unmodified copy of the demo app, using an unmodified copy of the library?

Comment: yup, I cloned the repo again, run CameraDemo and in DisplayActivity I still see a mirrored photo

Comment: It must be unique to your phone, then, as none of the devices I normally test exhibit this behavior. Just to confirm, your device is a [Samsung Galaxy S i9000](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9000_galaxy_s-3115.php)? And is there a letter after that model number? (i9000M, i9000T, i9000S)?

Comment: Perhaps the devices needs the portraitFFCFlipped setting in the device info? Even then, if it does have that setting, the  mirrorFFC() wouldn't be checked.

Comment: @CommonsWare the same issue happen on my Samsung Note 2 GT-N7100, Android 4.3 even with the CameraDemo, notice this is one of the Tested Device

Comment: @StevenLow: I cannot reproduce your findings on the GT-N7100, though mine is running 4.1.2, as "Software Update" says that it has the latest stuff and Samsung Kies is a bug-riddled piece of fecal material. :-(